# group by and then count missing variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks something like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Z = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 10000, replace = T),
  X1 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X2 = sample(c(1:25,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X3 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 10000, replace = T)
)
```

I can count the missing variables with:

```
data.frame("Total Missing" = colSums(is.na(df1)))
```

But, I would like to this by `Z`. That is, the number of missing X1-3 for each value of Z.

I tried this

```
df1 %>% group_by(Z) %>% summarise('Total Missing' = colSums(is.na(df1)))
```

but it does not work as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `summarise_each`:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Z) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
#Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
#
#       Z    X1    X2    X3
#  (fctr) (int) (int) (int)
#1      A   169    77   334
#2      B   170    77   316
#3      C   159    78   348
#4      D   181    79   326
#5      E   174    69   341
```

Note that you can specify inside `summarise_each` which columns to apply the function to (default is all columns except grouping columns) or which columns the function should *not* be applied to. It may also be interesting for you to note that like `summarise_each` to `summarise`, there's also `mutate_each` as the complement to `mutate` if you want to apply functions to all columns without summarising the result.

The obligatory data.table equivalent is:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(is.na(x))), by = Z]
#   Z  X1 X2  X3
#1: D 181 79 326
#2: C 159 78 348
#3: B 170 77 316
#4: A 169 77 334
#5: E 174 69 341
```

And in base R you could use a split/apply/combine approach like the following:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(
          split(df1, df1$Z), function(dd) {
            colSums(is.na(dd[-1]))
          }))
#   X1 X2  X3
#A 169 77 334
#B 170 77 316
#C 159 78 348
#D 181 79 326
#E 174 69 341
```

Or, also in base R, you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(df1[-1], list(df1$Z), FUN = function(y) sum(is.na(y))) 
aggregate(. ~ Z, df1, FUN = function(y) sum(is.na(y)), na.action = "na.pass") # formula interface
```