# Count total missing values by group?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, na

EDIT: input

very new to this.

I have a similar problem to this:
[group by and then count missing variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364196/group-by-and-then-count-missing-variables)

Taking the input data from that question:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Z = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 10000, replace = T),
  X1 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X2 = sample(c(1:25,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X3 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 10000, replace = T))
```

as one user proposed, it's possible to use `summarise_each`:

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Z) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
#Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
#
#       Z    X1    X2    X3
#  (fctr) (int) (int) (int)
#1      A   169    77   334
#2      B   170    77   316
#3      C   159    78   348
#4      D   181    79   326
#5      E   174    69   341
```

However, I would like to get only the total number of missing values per group.

I've also tried this but it didn't work: [R count NA by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477748/r-count-na-by-group)

Ideally, it should give me something like:

```
#       Z    sumNA 
#  (fctr)   (int) 
#1      A    580
#2      B    493
#3      C    585
#4      D    586
#5      E    584
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What's your input data for a given result?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Using the data in the first linked question, maybe `group_by(df1, Z) %>% summarize(n = sum(is.na(X1)))`? Those aren't the numbers you show here, but that may be due to the uncontrolled randomness (should have used `set.seed`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

df1[, .(sumNA = sum(is.na(.SD))), by = Z]

#    Z sumNA
# 1: A   559
# 2: C   661
# 3: E   596
# 4: B   597
# 5: D   560
```

`dplyr` solution using `rowSums(.[-1])`, i.e. row-sums for all columns except the first.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Z) %>% 
  summarise_all(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
  transmute(Z, sumNA = rowSums(.[-1]))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   Z     sumNA
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A       559
# 2 B       597
# 3 C       661
# 4 D       560
# 5 E       596
```

Comment: Great `data.table` way! You can also add a new column to original dataset: `setDT(df1)[, sumNA := sum(is.na(.SD)), by = Z]`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `tidyverse` approach.

```
require(tidyverse)
#Sample data
dat <- data.frame(group = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "g"), 3), 
                  y = rep(c(1, NA, 2, NA, 3), 3))


dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(sumNA = sum(is.na(y)))
```

Output:

```
  group sumNA
  <fct> <int>
1 a         0
2 b         3
3 c         0
4 d         3
5 g         0
```

## Edit

However, if you have more than one column, you can use `summarize_all` (or `summarize_at` if you'd like to specify the columns; thank you @ bschneidr for the comment):

```
#Sample data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(group = sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace = T), 
                  x = sample(c(1,NA), 10, replace = T), 
                  y = sample(c(1,NA), 10, replace = T), 
                  z = sample(c(1, NA), 10, replace = T))

dat %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize_all(.funs = funs('NA' = sum(is.na(.))))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group  x_NA  y_NA  z_NA
  <fct> <int> <int> <int>
1 a         1     1     0
2 b         3     2     2
3 c         0     1     1
4 d         1     4     2
```

Comment: What if I have more variables? I could type all the variables in sum(is.na(y+z+...)). But is there a way to do this without having to type every single variable?

Comment: You could use `summarize_at` from the dplyr package. For example, this would give you missing counts for two variables, X and Y: `data %>% group_by(group) %>% 
    summarize_at(.vars = vars(X, Y),
                 .funs = funs('NA' = sum(is.na(.))))`

Answer (score 2):

If your data looks like the linked post:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Z = as.factor(sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = 10000, replace = T)),
  X1 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X2 = sample(c(1:25,NA), 10000, replace = T),
  X3 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 10000, replace = T)
)
```

You can do the following in base R:

```
res <- sapply(split(df1[-1], f = df1$Z), function(x) colSums(is.na(x)))
print(res)
#     A   B   C   D   E
#X1 193 180 199 170 183
#X2  74  68  79  90  87
#X3 350 349 340 336 328
```

If you absolutely need it transposed, you can call `t(res)`:

```
print(t(res))
#   X1 X2  X3
#A 193 74 350
#B 180 68 349
#C 199 79 340
#D 170 90 336
#E 183 87 328
```

**Edit:** If you want the sum of all NAs and not within each variable the following small modification of the above works:

```
res2 <- sapply(split(df1[-1], f = df1$Z), function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
print(res2)
#  A   B   C   D   E 
#589 588 569 646 598
```

Alternatively, `colSums(res)` would give you the same. Again, `t()` if needed as a column.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want it split into X1, X2, X3. Just the total missing values per group.

Comment: @J.Ziegler So the sum of the NA's in all three columns for each level in Z? I've edited my answer.