# Searching for "NA"-Entries in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I've got a little problem. I'm new to R Studio and I don't find any tutorial on how to fix my problem.

So basically, I've got a dataframe with several elements. I'd like to have an overview about how many entries are "not available". This should be sorted by gender and task. I found out how to search the dataframe for the total amount of "NA"-Elements, but thats not what I'm searching.

My Dataframe looks like this (but with a lot more Information:

```
Gender Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
m     10     NA   10    5
w     NA     10   NA    5
w     10     10   5     4
```

So basically I just want to know how often the Task wasn't answered, for the different genders.

I hope someone can help me, I'm about to give up.

Thank you!

Comment: There are other ways. **This is a self promotion comment**: `mde::get_na_counts(df,grouping_cols="Gender")`. You can get `mde` [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/mde) if you prefer. Otherwise, I'll add an answer if none exists.

Comment: There are many ways. In base R you could do `by(x, x$Gender, summary)`

Comment: This is more useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195961/count-total-missing-values-by-group

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` and `is.na`.

```
aggregate(. ~ Gender, cbind(x[1], is.na(x[-1])), sum)
#  Gender Task1 Task2 Task3 Task4
#1      m     0     1     0     0
#2      w     1     0     1     0
```

Data:

```
x <- structure(list(Gender = c("m", "w", "w"), Task1 = c(10L, NA, 
10L), Task2 = c(NA, 10L, 10L), Task3 = c(10L, NA, 5L), Task4 = c(5L, 
5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```